# With `pytest --doctest-modules` is it possible to not capture exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, pytest, doctest

I use doctest for a very simple TDD approach by running the following command at a main entry point in any IDE/editor which supports debugging:

```
pytest.main(["--doctest-modules", "path/to/my/modules"])
```

I now just have to 'run my project' (press F5) to run all doctests - even in modules which can't be executed directly (this is why I'm running `pytest` instead of `doctest`).

This is working fine but could be even better if - in case of an unhandled exception - my IDE could jump to the location where it had been thrown (like it would when I run 'normal code').

For pytest there seems to be a way to [disable catching exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419998/how-can-i-get-pytest-to-not-catch-exceptions) but it looks like this doesn't work together with `--doctest-modules`.

Is there a way to let doctest behave the way I need it to? I'm looking for an approach which allows me to run doctest on modules.